# How do I check if a date is past due a numeric value in PHP

Tags: php, date

Hey guys so lets say I have a member who put 20 days.  So after 20 days if there member, lets say did not log in it would change there status.  But only based on a status change date which is written in MySQL database as `year-month-day`.  So if 20  days have done by his status change date than his status would change.

If you could give me a hand on how to do this I would appreciate it!

David

UPDATE:

code:

```
$newStatus = "Non-Active - Driver Chose Non-Compliance";

    $sql = "SELECT username,ATF FROM members WHERE username = 'test'";
    $getcsvuser = $DBH->prepare($sql);
    $getcsvuser->execute();
    while($row = $getcsvuser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $memusername = $row['username'];
        $memATF = $row['ATF'];
        if ($memATF != 0 || $memATF != "0")
        {
        $tsql = "SELECT username,status,memberview ,statuschangedate FROM csvdata WHERE memberview =:user";
        $tgetcsvuser = $DBH->prepare($tsql);
        $tgetcsvuser->execute(array(':user' => $memusername));
        while($trow = $tgetcsvuser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            $csvstatus = $trow['status'];
            $csvusername = $trow['username'];
            $csvdate = $trow['statuschangedate'];

            if($csvstatus == "Open" || $csvstatus == "Enrolled - Policyholder Follow-Up Required" || $csvstatus == "Enrolled - Employee Follow-Up Required" || $csvstatus == "Non-Active - Insurance Cancelled" || $csvstatus == "Non-Active, Unable to Monitor - Incidental Business use Exclusion" || $csvstatus == "Non-Active - Employee Not Covered Under Listed Policy" || $csvstatus == "Non-Active - PolicyHolder Cancelled Additional Interest")
            {

                $newsql = "UPDATE csvdata SET status = :newstatus WHERE statuschangedate < NOW() - INTERVAL :atf DAY AND username =:mem";
                $newgetcsvuser = $DBH->prepare($newsql);
                $newgetcsvuser->execute(array(':newstatus' => $newStatus, ':atf' => $memATF, ':mem' => $csvusername));
                while($rrow = $newgetcsvuser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    echo "working";
                }
            }

        }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Here's a clue: `strtotime('today - 20 days')`

Comment: @popnoodles so today would be the value of what ever the status change date was so like `2013-1-25`?

Comment: ok, if `strtotime('2012-12-19') < strtotime('today - 20 days')` then 2012-12-19 when they registered was more than 20 days ago

Comment: Oh wait, people are giving answers in SQL. I would use one of them.

Comment: @popnoodles I like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a combination of two things:

mysql to update the users, that are to be changed:

```
update
  members
set
  status = 'foo'
where
  status_change_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 20 DAY
```

The second part would be a cron job, that run that query daily.

Comment: That's what cron is for. Just google for `crontab` or `cron.daily`.

Comment: @DavidBiga yes, and I recommend that so that you can have the most up to date information in your database and you can avoid the added maintenance overhead of upadting a crontab

Comment: so can I use a :days instead of the 20?

Comment: sure, the actual number is variable, as long as it's bigger than 0

Comment: I would just run it for that user when they log in. No info given but it's quite likely only to be important when in the context of being logged in.

Comment: Ya I was going to run this through a $.ajax call every time the admin logged in because I don't know how to set it up where it will run no matter what if someone logs in or not.

Comment: here I am having difficultie using this:

Comment: `$newsql = "UPDATE csvdata SET status = :newstatus WHERE :date < NOW() - INTERVAL :atf DAY AND memberview =:mem";`

Comment: `:date` should be the date column in your table. why would you pass it along for every request? aside from that: what is the problem you encounter?

Comment: I am getting an error, it wont load...here I paste code in update

Comment: try fishing for the error like shown here: http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-mysql.php#69592. with the `try { .. } catch (PDOException $e) { ..}` you should get an explicit error message.

Comment: Error!: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: The weird thing is...the atf is 1?

Answer (score 1):

How about that:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET inactive = 1
WHERE date_field < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 DAY)
```

You could run this query as a `cronjob` once a night.

So this can be done without using PHP logic except for executing this SQL query.

Comment: From [DATE_ADD, DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add): "*These functions perform date arithmetic. The date argument specifies the starting date or datetime value. expr is an expression specifying the interval value to be added or subtracted from the starting date.*". It should work without the function too by simply subtracting both as provided in scones' answer.

Comment: Thanks...I'm gonna try the guy above first though.

Comment: Doesn't matter. They are virtually identical, just different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this but it should be close.

```
//$dbVal = $row["databaseColumn"];
$dbVal = "2013-01-24";  //For example
$now = Date();

$diff = abs($now - strtotime($dbVal));

$daysSince = floor(($diff/(60*60*24));
if ($daysSince >20){
    //Set status in DB;
}
```

incorporating @popnoodles solution:

```
//$dbVal = $row["databaseColumn"];
$dbVal = "2013-01-24";  //For example
$expireTime = 20;

$diff = strtotime($dbVal) - strtotime("today - $expireTime days");
if ($diff < 0 ){
    //Set status in DB;
}
```

Comment: what is today? and can I use a variable instead of the 20 days?  so lets say that var would be 20?

Comment: @DavidBiga today is today at the point the code is executed! strtotime calculates human readable dates to unix time.

Comment: @DavidBiga See my cahnge to allow for a variable number of days... Note the change of quotes from single quote to double quote.